# Number of homomorphisms from a stem field to a given field

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

This is a homework, but I've generalized it as possible in order not to have exact answer rather that to understand the very principle of solution.

The problem is following: consider $\mathbb{K}$ a field and $E$ an extension field of $\mathbb{K}$. For a given irreducible polynomial $P(x)$ from the ring $\mathbb K[x]$ find the number of homomorphisms from the stem field for $P(x)$ to the field $E$.

A stem  field for an irreducible polynomial $P$ in $\mathbb{K}[x]$ is a pair $(F,\alpha)$, where $\alpha$ is a root of $P$ and $F$ is an extension of $\mathbb{K}$, i.e. $F = \mathbb{K}[\alpha]$ and $P(\alpha)$=0

My understanding is following:

1. Any stem field $F$ is isomorphic to $
   \dfrac{\mathbb K[x]}{(P(x))}$
2. The number of homomorphisms from $\dfrac{\mathbb K[x]}{(P(x))}$ to $E$ is equal to the number of roots of this particular polynomial in $E$.

Example: if $\mathbb{K} = \mathbb{Q}$ and $P(x$) has $n$ roots in $\mathbb R$ (real roots) and $m$ complex (strictly non-real) roots, then the number of homomorphisms to $\mathbb R$ is `n` and number of homomorphisms to $\mathbb C$ is `n+m`.

Is my understanding correct at all? If not, can you give me a hint in what direction I should look for.

Comment: This is my first time hearing of the term "stem field" out of the context of "Science, Engineering, Technology and Mathematics". That's certainly an interesting word choice.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I've found this particular term for instance, in this book - http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/FT.pdf - if this term is not clear for English speaker - just let me know, and I'll add the definition of stem field to the question. Or if there's more appropriate term I will use it instead )

Comment: This is the second time in less than 8 hours that the term "stem field" appears in the site. The first time was from a finnish user, who said it was close to the term in finnish language but actually means "splitting field" . I couldn't find the term in Milne's book.

Comment: The term is mentioned in Milne's Fields and Galois Theory book and he in turn attributes it along with term root field(i.e. splitting field) to M.Albert's Modern Higher Algebra book from 1937. I guess its an arcane term not much in vogue now.

Comment: I have edited the question a bit and added the definition of a stem field. Are you referring to $E$ as an extension field of $\mathbb{K}$ or is it arbitrary? I am not sure.

Comment: @Vishesh, thanks! Yes, I've meant extension field. I've actually already submitted this homework and it now I'm even more sure that my understanding is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding is correct, except for one important assumption you've left out.  What you say is correct provided that $\mathbb{K}$ is a subfield of $E$ and you are only considering homomorphisms $F\to E$ which are the identity of $\mathbb{K}$.  In general, to define a homomorphism $\mathbb{K}[x]/(P(x))\to E$, you have to first choose a homomorphism $\varphi:\mathbb{K}\to E$, and then choose an element of $E$ which is a root of the polynomial obtained by applying $\varphi$ to the coefficients of $P$.  When you require $\varphi$ to be the inclusion map, this means your only choice is an element of $E$ which is a root of $P$.  But if you do not assume this, there may be many more homomorphisms $\mathbb{K}[x]/(P(x))\to E$ that do something else on $\mathbb{K}$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. Milne (in https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/FT.pdf section on "Stem Fields" in chapter 1) actually talks about homomorphism of F-algebras (in this case, $\mathbb{K}$-algebras) that is defined as a homomorphism whose restriction on F is the identity (see section "Fields" in chapter 1). Similarly, I guess the homework comes from a Coursera course on Galois Theory, and even there the isomorphism in bullet 1 of the original post is "of $\mathbb{K}$-algebras".